# Get Ip Address WPF and C# Display Issue

Tags: c#, ip-address

anyone know why when I run this code

```
            IPHostEntry
         IPHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach
         (var
         ipAddress in
         IPHost.AddressList)
        {

            IPlabel.Content = ipAddress;
        }
```

It returns it in a format of: 2001:1:9d39:6 ...?

Id be looking to get this in format of IPv4: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Not sure if theirs a duplicate post or not, I've been looking for quite some time. I might not be using the right search key words

Appreciate any help &or post you folks could provide.

Comment: Could it be an IPv6 address?

Comment: That is a global IPv6 address. You can't get it as an IPv4 address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this has been answered here?
[Getting the ip-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029230/getting-the-ip-address)

```
// return the first IPv4, non-dynamic/link-local, non-loopback address
public static IPAddress GetIPAddress()
{
    IPAddress[] hostAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses("");

    foreach (IPAddress hostAddress in hostAddresses)
    {
        if (hostAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork &&
            !IPAddress.IsLoopback(hostAddress) &&  // ignore loopback addresses
            !hostAddress.ToString().StartsWith("169.254."))  // ignore link-local addresses
            return hostAddress;
    }
    return null; // or IPAddress.None if you prefer
}
```