# WPF C#. Can't display the IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Can't display the IPv4 and IPv6. I attached my C#. My goal is to display IP address, IPv4 and IPv6 address with XAML. The problem cannot display both IPv4 and IPv6 at the moment. IP address and hostname can be displayed.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window {
     public MainWindow() {
         InitializeComponent();

         string hostName = Dns.GetHostName(); // Retrive the Name of HOST
                                              // Get the IP
         NetworkModel model = new NetworkModel();
         string IPv4 = String.Empty;

         // IPv4
         model.IPAddress = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
         model.HostName = Dns.GetHostName();
         model.IPv4 = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork.ToString();
         model.IPv6 = System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6.ToString();

         DataContext = model;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the ip-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029230/getting-the-ip-address)

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "can't display", do you mean it's throwing an exception, or is it displaying a blank for certain fields? If it's coming up blank, maybe there simply isn't a v6 IP address to display?